# Subprocess access denied error when running nmap as System User

Tags: python, windows, nmap

I'm trying to run a python script when the system boots on a Windows 10 workstation. My python script runs fine when I kick it off in a different directory  as a user with administrative privileges but when I run it from a bat file in the C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts\Startup folder on system boot I receive the following error in my logs.

```
2018-11-13 04:43:58,913 - VP - Level 55 - nmap args: ['"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Nmap\\nmap.exe"', '-oX', 'C:\\\\nmap\\NmapResults\\scan-192.168.1.5-20181113044358.xml', '-sS', '-n', '-p-', '--allports', '--scan-delay', '1ms', '-sU', '-sV', '--version-all', '192.168.1.5']

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "secnmap\nmap_scanner.py", line 596, in <module>

    exit_code = main()

  File "secnmap\nmap_scanner.py", line 248, in main

    run_nmap(args, scan_options, host_data_list, use_service_name_check)

  File "secnmap\nmap_scanner.py", line 268, in run_nmap

    nmap_proc = subprocess.Popen(nmap_cmd_list, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__

    errread, errwrite)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 640, in _execute_child

    startupinfo)

WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied
```

Here is the content of the .bat file.

```
cd C:\\nmap_startup
python nmap_startup.py
```

I have tried using the full nmap.exe path as shown in the code snippet as well as plain old `nmap`. I get the access denied error either way. I didn't see much in subprocess.py that would lead me to believe this to be an error with the python code either so I am leaning on it being an issue with System user running the script. If someone thinks otherwise or has any ideas, I'd love to hear them. Thanks

EDIT: I chose to run from a bat file because my python version is 32bit and I was having issues running from the C:\windows\system32 directory

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the path to nmap, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap`, was not included in the system environment variables. When the script ran as a System user, it did not recognize the location of nmap